# I chanaged the sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config sftp to be internal only and now can't login

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am locked out of SSH to manage my instance on Google Cloud Platform.  I have a website running, but I can't manage it on an Ubuntu server because I can't login to control it.  The sshd service was failing to start and I rebooted and now I can't login with Google SDK.  I changed the sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to be internal sftp only.  Now SSH does not work for login from the Google SDK.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably you made a syntax error in **sshd** config. Log in through the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) and check ssh log for errors (depends on distribution, but probably `systemctl -u ssh -e` will work).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to SSH your VM instance, you have two options:

1.- You can run [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) over your VM Instance IP address to verify the ports and services that are listening. Connect to your VM Instance via serial port by following this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#debug_with_serial_console), this will allow you to fix the configuration over /etc/ssh/sshd_config, also verify [ssh service](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restart-ssh/) is up and running.

2.- You can [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of your VM instance 1, then, create a second VM Instance, [attach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) this snapshot disk to it, this way you will be able to access the data from VM Instance 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login from another internal instance (in same vpc )as you have enabled internal ssh.
then change ssh config settings as it was earlier.

Comment: I have to create a new instance in google cloud platform and remote in form another server at the location?  I will try this.  Thanks